# Username specified in a server.xml for MQ connection factory is ignored (tomcat based container)

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, containers, ibm-mq

I have two docker containers:

- MQ container (ibmcom/mq:9.1.4.0-r1 image). Also I have added "tomcat"
  and "testuser" users in mqm group.
- Tomcat-based container with my    app (tomcat:9-jre8-alpine image)
  runs as "tomcat" user.

When I run tomcat container I get the following error in AMQERR01.LOG file of mq container (pay attention to CLNTUSER):

> Process(665.16654) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
> Host(db9867e9a10a) Installation(Installation1)
> VRMF(9.1.4.0) QMgr(MYQMGR)
> Time(2021-09-21T13:34:20.018Z)
> RemoteHost(XXX.XX.X.X)
> CommentInsert1(MYCHANNEL)
> CommentInsert2(myapp (XXX.XX.X.X))
> CommentInsert3(CLNTUSER(tomcat) ADDRESS(myapp))
> AMQ9777E: Channel was blocked
> EXPLANATION:
> The inbound channel 'MYCHANNEL' was blocked from address 'myapp (XXX.XX.X.X)' because the active values of the channel matched a record configured with USERSRC(NOACCESS). The active values of the channel were '**CLNTUSER(tomcat)** ADDRESS(myapp)'.

My server.xml:

```
   <Resource name="jdbc/MyDataSource"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              username="db_user"
              password="db_pass"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="$[DB_URL]"
              validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />

    <Resource name="jms/MyRequestConnFactory"
              auth="Container"
              type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"
              factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory"
              username="testuser"
              password="cfpass"
              HOST="mq"
              PORT="1418"
              CHAN="MYCHANNEL"
              TRAN="1"
              QMGR="MYQMGR" />

    <Resource name="jms/MyResponseConnFactory"
              auth="Container"
              type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"
              factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory"
              username="testuser"
              password="cfpass"
              HOST="mq"
              PORT="1418"
              CHAN="MYCHANNEL"
              TRAN="1"
              QMGR="MYQMGR" />

    <Resource name="jms/MyRequestQueue"
              auth="Container"
              type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue"
              factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueFactory"
              QU="A_TO_B_QUEUE" />

    <Resource name="jms/MyResponseQueue"
              auth="Container"
              type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue"
              factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueFactory"
              QU="B_TO_A_QUEUE" />
```

I'm sure that server.xml itself is not ignored because I can successfully connect to a database, and when I changed HOST to a different value I got a "can't resolve hostname" error or smth like that.
But for some reason, the "username" attribute (and I think "password" as well) is ignored.

When I ran tomcat container as root, I got the same error as above but this time CLNTUSER=root.
So instead of username specified in the server.xml application trying to connect using the current container user.

Can someone explain to me why?
Could application implementation be the issue?

UPD:
Here is output of the first command:

> DIS QMGR CONNAUTH
> 1 : DIS QMGR CONNAUTH
> AMQ8408I: Display Queue Manager details.
> QMNAME(MY_QMGR)                   CONNAUTH(USE.PW)

Second command output:

> DIS AUTHINFO(USE.PW)
> 1 : DIS AUTHINFO(USE.PW)
> AMQ8566I: Display authentication information details.
> AUTHINFO(USE.PW)                        AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS)
> ADOPTCTX(YES)                           DESCR( )
> CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED)                      CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL)
> FAILDLAY(10)                            AUTHENMD(OS)
> ALTDATE(2021-09-20)                     ALTTIME(14.07.42)

DIS CHLAUTH(*) ALL output:

```
DIS CHLAUTH(*) ALL  
     1 : DIS CHLAUTH(*) ALL  
AMQ8878I: Display channel authentication record details.  
   CHLAUTH(DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN)              TYPE(USERMAP)  
   DESCR(Allows admin user to connect via ADMIN channel)  
   CUSTOM( )                               ADDRESS( )  
   CLNTUSER(admin)                         USERSRC(CHANNEL)  
   CHCKCLNT(ASQMGR)                        ALTDATE(2021-09-20)  
   ALTTIME(14.07.40)  
AMQ8878I: Display channel authentication record details.  
   CHLAUTH(DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN)              TYPE(BLOCKUSER)  
   DESCR(Allows admins on ADMIN channel)   CUSTOM( )  
   USERLIST(nobody)                        WARN(NO)  
   ALTDATE(2021-09-20)                     ALTTIME(14.07.40)  
AMQ8878I: Display channel authentication record details.  
   CHLAUTH(DEV.APP.SVRCONN)                TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)  
   DESCR(Allows connection via APP channel)  
   CUSTOM( )                               ADDRESS(*)  
   USERSRC(CHANNEL)                        CHCKCLNT(ASQMGR)  
   ALTDATE(2021-09-20)                     ALTTIME(14.07.40)  
AMQ8878I: Display channel authentication record details.  
   CHLAUTH(SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN)           TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)  
   DESCR(Default rule to allow MQ Explorer access)  
   CUSTOM( )                               ADDRESS(*)  
   USERSRC(CHANNEL)                        CHCKCLNT(ASQMGR)  
   ALTDATE(2021-09-20)                     ALTTIME(14.07.38)  
AMQ8878I: Display channel authentication record details.  
   CHLAUTH(SYSTEM.*)                       TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)  
   DESCR(Default rule to disable all SYSTEM channels)  
   CUSTOM( )                               ADDRESS(*)  
   USERSRC(NOACCESS)                       WARN(NO)  
   ALTDATE(2021-09-20)                     ALTTIME(14.07.38)  
AMQ8878I: Display channel authentication record details.  
   CHLAUTH(*)                              TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)  
   DESCR(Back-stop rule - Blocks everyone)  
   CUSTOM( )                               ADDRESS(*)  
   USERSRC(NOACCESS)                       WARN(NO)  
   ALTDATE(2021-09-20)                     ALTTIME(14.07.40)  
AMQ8878I: Display channel authentication record details.  
   CHLAUTH(*)                              TYPE(BLOCKUSER)  
   DESCR(Default rule to disallow privileged users)  
   CUSTOM( )  
   USERLIST(*MQADMIN)                      WARN(NO)  
   ALTDATE(2021-09-20)                     ALTTIME(14.07.38)
```

Comment: By default users in the mqm group will be blocked.   Do you have CONNAUTH enabled?  Run `DIS QMGR CONNAUTH` then if there is a value filled in run `DIS AUTHINFO(<value from dis qmgr>)`.  Please edit the question and provide the output from both commands.

Comment: Sorry for late response.
I have updated question with requested outputs.
But I don't understand what it has to do with the username attribute being ignored.
For now I have no problem with blocked users, I'm wondering why "testuser" is not used for connection.

Comment: The error you posted says `AMQ9777E: Channel was blocked`, is this not the case?

Comment: I'm asking why error description says CLNTUSER=tomcat, if in server.xml I set username to "testuser"?

Comment: Check you queue manager logs for an entry that mentions testuser probably directly above the channel blocked error.  Did it have a permission error or bad password error?   Can you add the output of `DIS CHLAUTH(*) ALL` to your question please.

Comment: I checked AMQERR log and json files. but testuser doesn't mentioned in any of them.
These logs just filled with the same error over and over again because of application continuously trying to connect.

I've updated error description and added output of DIS CHLAUTH(*) ALL

Comment: Is your channel called DEV.APP.SVRCONN or is it really called MYCHANNEL? If it is MYCHANNEL then you need a CHLAUTH rule like the rule for DEV.APP.SVRCONN to allow it to be used,  otherwise it will be blocked by the back stop rule.

Comment: Well, when I run my app I get the following error in docker logs for mq container:
AMQ9999E: Channel 'MYCHANNEL' to host 'XXX.XX.X.X' ended abnormally.
Sorry, but I'm not sure how I can add this rule to 20-config file.

Comment: How do you add the extra MYCHANNEL?  You can either add the CHLAUTH rule or you could use DEV.APP.SVRCONN which already has the rule.

Comment: I've managed to fix my problem.
Instead of adding testuser to mqm group, I had to add it to mqclient group. Now testuser is using for connection.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: The last CHLAUTH rule you listed blocks all MQADMIN users from connecting.